# Overlap of two time periods

Tags: python, datetime

I have two dataframes.

The one contains workers shift time with a start date and an end date.

The other is "downtime" which has a start time and an end time.

Both data frames look like the following:

```
    Start Date                  End Date               

43  2018-10-01 05:00:00+00:00   2018-10-03 05:00:00+00:00   
44  2018-09-27 13:00:00+00:00   2018-10-01 05:00:00+00:00 
45  2018-09-27 10:10:00+00:00   2018-09-27 13:00:00+00:00
```

I'm trying to find the amount of time that employees actually work. Only time which is not downtime should be counted.

I have thought of two methods of solving this (which give slightly different results)

The first one is a "brute force method" where I create a new dataframe that contains a record of every minute in the year. I combined this with shift time so that all worker time was split into 1 minute intervals. I then used the following code

```
removed_stuff = pd.DataFrame(columns=["shift","columns"])

for i in range(len(downtime)):

    removed_stuff = pd.concat([removed_stuff,test_copy[(test_copy.index <= downtime["End Date"][i]) & (test_copy.index >= downtime["Start Date"][i])]])

    test_copy = test_copy[(test_copy.index > downtime["End Date"][i]) | (test_copy.index < downtime["Start Date"][i])]
```

removed_stuff is all the stuff that was removed that was inside the planned_stoppage_reasons start and end time. test_copy is what I want and contains all time that is outside of any downtime.

When summing the amount of minutes of test_copy I (should) get the total amount of minutes that were outside of any downtime that was worked.

My other idea is a bit more hand wavy.

I combined the downtime and workers shift into a single dataframe:

```
time                   shift start  shift end stoppage start    stoppage end    
2018-01-02 06:00:00+00:00   NaN     NaN     1.0     NaN 
2018-01-02 18:30:00+00:00   NaN     NaN     NaN     1.0 
2018-01-04 06:00:00+00:00   1.0     NaN     NaN     NaN 
2018-01-04 18:00:00+00:00   NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN 
2018-01-05 06:00:00+00:00   1.0     NaN     NaN     NaN 
2018-01-05 18:00:00+00:00   NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN
```

I then create a new column which gets written in the following way.

```
def actaul_shift(Dataframe,first_value):

    Dataframe_new = Dataframe.copy()

    Dataframe_new["actual"][0] = first_value

    for i in range(len(Dataframe_new)):
        if i != 0:
            if Dataframe_new["shift start"][i] == 1:
                Dataframe_new["actual"][i] = Dataframe_new["actual"][i - 1] + 1
            elif Dataframe_new["shift end"][i] == 1:
                Dataframe_new["actual"][i] = Dataframe_new["actual"][i -1] - 1
            elif Dataframe_new["stoppage start"][i] == 1:
                Dataframe_new["actual"][i] = Dataframe_new["actual"][i -1] - 1
            elif Dataframe_new["stoppage end"][i] == 1:
                Dataframe_new["actual"][i] = Dataframe_new["actual"][i -1] + 1

    return Dataframe_new
```

I have to specify the very first value (which is just whether the machine should be on or off at the first moment in time), after that if shift start == 1 then the column actual should add 1 to previous value, if shift end == 1 then minus 1 to previous value, if stoppage start == 1 then minus 1 to previous value and if stoppage end == 1 then add 1 to previous value.

Essentially I then only care when the number transitions from 1 to 0 (on to off).

If the machine start in an off state (0) then downtime start (-1) then the shift start (0) then downtime ends (1) then shift ends (0). only the final 1 to 0 counts as the machine was down the rest of the time.

Running a few examples on a piece of paper seems to always make sense.

However the results I get from the two method give slightly different results. The results are large enough (9% different) that I cannot explain it away through simple rounding errors from the first method ( I even ran it with 1 second intervals and the result was still different).

Are either of these methods correct. If so is there a more efficient method if not is there a correct method.

Many Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this type of math by hand.  You should look at `datetime.strptime` to parse the times into datetime objects.  They support addition and subtraction to produce `datetime.timedelta` objects which represent a span of time.  A timedelta minus another timedelta produces an accurate result.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry I'm not familiar with 'datetime.strptime'. I've looked at the what is written about it but can't quite understand what it does. If I had 

    Shift Start 2018-01-02 06:00:00
    Shift End 2018-01-02 18:30:00
    Downtime Start 2018-01-02 10:00:00
    Downtime End 2018-01-02 20:00:00

Where the total worked time is 4 hours how would I go about doing this with 'datetime.strptime'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working from the requested example in the comments, and with the condition that downtime can actually fall outside of worked shift hours (which feels wrong, but hey, it's your data) you could find the total time worked of four hours with these steps:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
>>> S1 = datetime.strptime('2018-01-02 06:00:00', fmt)
>>> E1 = datetime.strptime('2018-01-02 18:30:00', fmt)
>>> S2 = datetime.strptime('2018-01-02 10:00:00', fmt)
>>> E2 = datetime.strptime('2018-01-02 20:00:00', fmt)

>>> shift = max(E1, E2) - min(S1, S2)
>>> downtime = E2 - S2
>>> worked = shift - downtime
>>> worked.seconds
14400
>>> worked.seconds / 60 / 60
4.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So my data has over around 250 downtime periods and over 3000 work periods. I'm not sure how easy this answer would be to apply to the whole dataframe. Additionally downtime can completely go over multiple work periods making it more complicated.